# EC2 security group setting for load balancer, auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy, autoscaling, amazon-elb

So I set up a proxy server in AWS `EC2` (let's say `EC2` **A**) under `Elastic Load Balancer` with AWS `AutoScaling` groups... So I have 5 of `EC2 : A` under this elastic load balancer that has one DNS server endpoint for this proxies.

Through this proxy DNS (e.g. http://myelb.elb.aws.com), I want to send `HTTP` request from `EC2` **B**.

Then where should I set up the security group?

And what kind of security rules for this program flow?

I tried to add `EC2` **A** to the `Elastic Load Balancer` but it keeps being `OutofService`, never got to `InService` mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OutofService** indicates that your Elastic Load Balancer is either not ready, or the instances are failing their **Health Check**. If you point to the little "i" information icon, it will explain why an instance is not InService.

Within your Elastic Load Balancer, take a look at the **Health Check** tab and confirm that it is configured correctly. It will either be checking a URL (eg /index.htm) or checking a port (eg port 80). If your "A" servers are listening on port 80, the quickest way to pass the health check is to set it to **TCP** and set the **Healthy Threshold** to 2 attempts.

Your Security Groups should have these settings:

- **A Security Group on your Elastic Load Balancer** (eg ELB-SG) that allows incoming traffic either from the whole Internet (0.0.0.0/0) or at least from your "EC2 B" instance (specifically, it should allow traffic where the source is the name of a security group associated with your B instance).
- **A Security Group on your "EC2 A" instances** that allows incoming traffic from the security group on your Load Balancer (ELB-SG).

If you are worried that your Security Groups are incorrectly configured, start troubleshooting by opening up access to the entire Internet (0.0.0.0/0) and, once you have confirmed connectivity, progressively reduce access to the above settings.